# Rails SQLite3 DB locks trying to multithread object update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, sqlite

I have an application that need to spawn multiple thread and in each thread updates the database. When I only spawn 1 thread and do the update in series, everything is fine, but when trying to multithread I get errors in the log:

> SQLite3::SQLException: SQL logic error or missing database: rollback transaction
>   and
>   SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked

I assume the locking is because of the first error.

Here is the code that causes the issue:

```
all_threads = []
servers.each do |server|
  all_threads << Thread.new(server) do |svr|
    serverCurrent = Server.find(svr.id)
    serverCurrent.state = 3
    serverCurrent.save
  end
end
all_threads.each(&:join)
```

If I loop over servers inside the thread (so only one thread is created everything is fine). The database I am using is SQLite3

Comment: Just updated to mysql with mysql2 gem, seems to have fixed the problem. Couldn't get SQLite3 to work.

Answer (score 0):

Threading support in SQLite3 is dependent on which options were used at compile time.

Details about SQLite3 threading:
http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

Possible solutions:
http://dev.yorhel.nl/doc/sqlaccess